# The /ɪ/ sound vs the /i/ sound - exact difference?

Tags: phonetics

What's the exact difference in the 'pi' sound between 'happiness' **/ˈhæp.i.nəs/** and epicentre **/ˈep.ɪ.sen.tər/** that prompts the Cambridge Dictionary compilers to use a diffrerent vowel code for each case? More generally, what's the exact difference between the /ɪ/ sound and the /i/ sound, is it just in the duration (in some contexts?)? Is it just a historical variation that's lingereing? Or is there something more to it?

**Edit:**
After posting this question, I hit these two blog posts that are discussing the issue in detail:

- http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2012/06/happy-again.html
- https://www.englishspeechservices.com/blog/the-fallac%C9%AAjof-schwee/

One takeaway is that the /i/ sound was introduced to denote possible alternative pronunciations /ɪ/ and /i:/.

After reading the two posts, I still have questions:

- What's the point of using the /i/ in the middle of a word, I'm not aware that there are alternative pronunciations for happiness?!
- Is there still accents around that pronounce happy as /ˈhæp.i:/? And why is it not just considered allophonic variation anyway? When I listen to the standard dictionary pronunciations they seem to be somewhere between an /ɪ/ and /i:/ in duration, but in real life I hear native speakers normally pronounce it as /ˈhæp.ɪ/.

Comment: It's the difference between "peat" and "pit". Although I suppose there may be people who pronounce "pi" in "epicenter" as "pee", in which case the distinction would be lost.

Comment: No it's not. That's /piːt/  vs /pɪt/, and that's not what we're discussing here.

Comment: Not all phonologists/linguists/teachers use the length mark. See "[The Undesirability of length marks in EFL phonemic transcription](http://www.yek.me.uk/undesire.html)", (1975), by Jack Windsor Lewis. Especially in transcriptions of American English, it's common to represent the vowel in *peat* as /i/. The pronunciation of the vowel in words like "happy" varies between accents; a three-way distinction in transcription between /iː/, /i/ and /ɪ/ lets you include more information for multiple accents at once, but specific accents only have a two-way distinction if you take stress into account.

Comment: The introduction of /i/ as distinct from /i:/ for English phonemes was one of the stupidest things that phonologists have ever done. (a) there are apparently a small number of English speakers who have three different phonemes:  /i:/, /i/, /ɪ/. Given the number of people where this happens, it should have been ignored. We don't use two IPA symbols because New Yorkers pronounce *class* and *clap* differently. (continued)

Comment: (b) there are some people who use /iː/ in *happy* and some people who use /ɪ/. The proper way of treating this would be to write "/ˈhæpiː/, /ˈhæpɪ/" or maybe "/ˈhæpiː, -pɪ /". Using /i/ to mean alternative pronunciations just causes confusion.

Comment: @PeterShor The short /a/ isn’t a very good parallel, because that’s pretty predictable: the phoneme has developed different allophones based on (morpho)phonetic context. That’s a classic case for **not** indicating a difference in phonemic writing, because the different allophones can be combined into one phoneme. The /i/ phoneme is a different thing: it’s a (morpho)phonemic context where none of the available phonemes fit properly. There are no constraints that can align /i/ properly with either /iː/ or /ɪ/, but it’s too systematic to just give alternative pronunciations for all words.

Comment: @PeterShor There are many words which have varying pronunciations, but those are characterised by being unpredictable: which syllable is stressed in _adult_ is arbitrary, often even with the same speaker. With /i/, on the other hand, a speaker will usually have the same variant everywhere: if you pronounce _happy_ with an [ɪ], you’ll also pronounce _epicentre_ with that sound. That’s characteristic of phonemes, not of arbitrary variation.

Comment: @BazAU Re: "That's /piːt/ vs /pɪt/, and that's not what we're discussing here". I thought that what you describe _is_ the difference between high front with an off-glide vs mid front. (at least in standard Gen Am E. If, as you say, it is not about that, can you explain how it's different?

Comment: @Janus: what makes it confusing is that this is the only IPA symbol used this way in English. We don't use three IPA symbols for *cat*, *bath*, and *father*, which is probably a much better parallel.

Comment: @PeterShor It’s not the only one, though the parallel /u/ is less common. The _bath_ vowel is indeed a much better parallel. Personally, I think it would be preferable if IPA used to describe English across dialects included phonemic representations of all the lexical-set vowels (including a separate symbol for _bath_). Lexical sets are sort of pseudo-phonemics that don’t play nicely with IPA. That would also make /i/ and /u/ less edge cases and help reduce confusion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The /i/ sound is just the short version of /i:/; without the `ː` length mark it is shorter.
Just as you can find /i:/ in words like *p**e**at*, the /i/ sound is found in words like *happ**i**ness* where the vowel is shorter.
In *epicentre*, you can find an /ɪ/ because, in many accents, such as the Cambridge Dictionary's main focus of BrE, it is not any sort of *ee* sound, but an **ih** sound, as found in *h**i**t*.

That said, there are different ways of utilizing IPA, and as @sumelic has mentioned, some linguists choose to steer clear of the length mark.  I'm writing from a sort of standardized, Oxford Dictionary-type point of view─BrE, length marks etc.  I can't really speak for AmE, but, as you spelt *epicentre*  and not *epicenter*, I guess this doesn't really apply ;)

See the OED's helpful IPA [page](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-pronunciation/) for more info and AmE insight.

Comment: But /i:/ can be unstressed too: proceeds /ˈprəʊ.siːdz/. And if it's just a matter of stress, why should there be a distinction in the phonetic transcription, because other vowels are not using such a distinction!

Comment: @BazAU Correct.  I have realised this was false─it's a matter of length.

Comment: @BazAU: In some traditions, words like "proceeds" are transcribed with some stress on the second syllable:  /ˈprəʊˌsiːdz/ (Balogné Bérces Katalin calls this "tertiary stress", in contrast to the more widely recognized secondary stress that occurs on a syllable preceding the accented/primary-stressed syllable). I made a post about it here: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/433879/77227