# Which syllable is primarily stressed in the word "television"?

Tags: stress

I was taught to stress the first syllable of "television", but some dictionaries stress the syllable before -sion. My other question is "Does stressing VI before -sion exist in AmE?

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/television) says that putting the primary stress (or accent) on the second-to-last syllable of *television* is an "especially British" pronunciation.

I'm an American English speaker, and I don't remember ever hearing that pronunciation.

In American English, the pronunciation with primary stress on the first syllable may be analyzed as having [tertiary stress](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/433879/77227) on the second-to-last syllable: *ˈteleˌvision.*

Comment: Yes, and in American English, "1tele3vision" has the same 1 3 stress pattern as the verb "1tele3vise".

Comment: I'd say the version with the stress on the second last syllable is fairly uncommon in BrE.